# Neo4jError: Message 'COMMIT' cannot be handled by a session in the READY state

Tags: node.js, neo4j, neo4j-javascript

Im new to neo4j (playing with neo4j-Desktop 1.2.4 on a 4.0.0 neo4j-DB the last week) and I started today with the neo4j-javascript-driver (version 4.0.1) in node.js. I've gone through the [neo4j-driver doc for javascript](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver) and [the official neo4j Documentation for Drivers](https://neo4j.com/docs/driver-manual/current/) and found no clue on the state of the session.

The minimum code file 'Neo4jDB.js' is:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");

const cfg = require('../config/config_all');
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver');

var driver = neo4j.driver(
    cfg.neo4j.uri,
    neo4j.auth.basic(cfg.neo4j.user,cfg.neo4j.password),
    { maxTransactionRetryTime: 30000}
    );

function Neo4jDB() { // NJDBxx

    this.cleanUp = function() {
        var session = driver.session();
        session.close();
        driver.close();
    }

    function error2msg(msgid,error,msgclass) {
        if (typeof error.msgid === 'string' || typeof msgid === 'undefined' ) {
            return error;
        }
        if (typeof msgclass === 'undefined') {
            msgclass = 'DatabaseError';
        }
        return {
            msgid : msgid,
            msg : error,
            msgclass : msgclass,
        }
    }

    function pt_createAuthor(txc,author) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            if (typeof author !== 'object' || typeof author.name !== 'string') {
                reject(error2msg('NJAT01','ParameterError in Author creation',"ParameterError"));
                return;
            }
            txc.run("MERGE (a:Author { name:$nameParam }) "
                    +"RETURN a.name AS name",
                    {nameParam: author.name})
            .then(authors => {
                resolve(authors);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log("p_createAuthor-error:",error);
                txc.rollback();
                reject(error2msg('NJAT02',error));
            });
        });
    }

    function pt_createBook(txc,book) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            if (typeof book !== 'object' || typeof book.title !== 'string' || typeof book.isbn !== 'string') {
                reject(error2msg('NJBO01','ParameterError in Book creation',"ParameterError"));
                return;
            }
            txc.run("MERGE (b:Book { title: $titleParam,isbn:$isbnParam }) "
                    +"RETURN b.title AS title,b.isbn AS isbn",
                    {titleParam: book.title,isbnParam : book.isbn})
            .then(books => {
                resolve(books);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log("pt_createBook-error:",error);
                reject(error2msg('NJBO02',error));
            })
        });
    }
    function pt_relateBookAndAuthor(txc,authorname,isbn) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            if (typeof authorname !== 'string' || typeof isbn !== 'string') {
                reject(error2msg('NJBO03','ParameterError in Book relation to Author', "ParameterError"));
                return;
            }
            txc.run("MATCH (a:Author),(b:Book) WHERE a.name = $authorParam AND b.isbn = $isbnParam "
                +"CREATE (b)-[r:isAuthor]->(a) RETURN type(r) ",
                {authorParam: authorname,isbnParam : isbn})
                .then(rel => {
                    resolve(rel);
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log("pt_relateBookAndAuthor-error:",error);
                    reject(error2msg('NJBO02',error)); 
                })
        });
    }

    this.createBookAndAuthor = function(book,author) {
        var session,txc;
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            if (typeof book !== 'object' || typeof book.title !== 'string' || typeof book.isbn !== 'string') {
                reject(error2msg('NJBO03','ParameterError in Book creation',"ParameterError"));
                return;
            }
            if (typeof author !== 'object' || typeof author.name !== 'string') {
                reject(error2msg('NJAT03','ParameterError in Author creation',"ParameterError"));
                return;
            }
            session = driver.session({database:'',defaultAccessMode: neo4j.session.WRITE});
            txc = session.beginTransaction();
            pt_createBook(txc,book)
            .then(function(result){
                console.log('result-1');
                return pt_createAuthor(txc,author);
            },function(error){
                txc.rollback();
                session.close();
                reject(error2msg(undefined,error)); 
            }).then(function(result){
                if (typeof result === 'undefined') {
                    return;
                }
                console.log('result-2');
                return pt_relateBookAndAuthor(txc,author.name,book.isbn);
            },function(error){
                txc.rollback();
                session.close();
                reject(error2msg(undefined,error));
            })
            .then(function(result){
                if (typeof result === 'undefined') {
                    return;
                }
                console.log('result-3');
                txc.commit()
                  .then( () => console.log("commit success"))
                  .catch( (error) => console.log("commit failed: ",error));
                session.close();
                resolve(book);
            },function(error){
                txc.rollback();
                session.close();
                reject(error2msg(undefined,error));
            });
        });
    }
};
module.exports = new Neo4jDB();
```

I'm using three discrete routines `pt_createAuthor`, `pt_createAuthor`, `pt_relateBookAndAuthor`. Despite of using one cypher-Statement for the whole task, I've splitted the transaction into these 3 and other basic functions, so that I can combine them in a similar pattern as used in the `createBookAndAuthor`-Routine also in other comfort routines (one session and one transaction, multiple basic functions).

Currently I'm using some concrete sample data in a spec file:

```
const pdb = require('./Neo4jDB');
const assert = require('assert');


describe('Neo4jDB',function(){
    describe('First Book',function(){
        var author1 = {
            name:'Boris Grundl'
        };
        var author2 = {
            name:'Bodo Schäfer'
        }
        var book1 = {
            title: 'Leading simple',
            subtitle: 'Führen kann so einfach sein',
            isbn: '978-3-89749-708-5',
        }
        it('create pook with 1st author',function(done) {
            pdb.createBookAndAuthor(book1,author1)
            .then(function(result){
                // console.log(result);
                done();
            },function(error){
                console.log(error);
                done(error);
            })
        })
        it('merge book with 2nd author',function(done) {
            pdb.createBookAndAuthor(book1,author2)
            .then(function(result){
                // console.log(result);
                done();
            },function(error){
                console.log(error);
                done(error);
            })
        })
        it('cleans up',function(done){
            pdb.cleanUp();
            done();
        })
    }) // Connection tests.
}); // Neo4jDB
```